# Cannot resolve method setListAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview

I try to show listView in fragment. But method setListAdapter - is not resolved.
I think, that i must to get id of listView (android.R.id.list);
and then : lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);but its dont work too.

```
public class MyEmployeeFragment extends Fragment {

    private CustomAdapter sAdapter;
    private List<User> userList;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        sAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),userList);
        setListAdapter(sAdapter);
        new CustomAsync().execute();

    }

    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<User> objects) {
            super(context, 0, objects);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView id;
            TextView name;
            TextView lastName;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder vH;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_employee, null);
                vH = new ViewHolder();
                vH.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_employee_id);
                vH.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_employee_name);
                vH.lastName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_employee_last_name);
                convertView.setTag(vH);
            } else
                vH = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


            final User user = getItem(position);
            vH.id.setText(user.getId());
            vH.name.setText(user.getName());
            vH.lastName.setText(user.getLastName());


            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private class CustomAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<User>>
    {}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#B7B7B7"

        />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="83dp">
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your asynctask does noting

Comment: Its just for stackOverflow. In app async code is excist

Comment: you can do as suggested in my post if you want fragment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setListAdapter` is a method of `ListFragment` while your fragment extends `Fragment`.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29)

So you either extend `ListFragment`

or

Extend `Fragment` inflate a layout with `ListView`, initialize `ListView` in `onCreateView` of `Fragment` and then use `listView.setAdapter(adapter)`.

In case you want to extend Fragment

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
```

Then

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourxml, container, false);

ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(youradapter);

return rootView;
}
```

Comment: There is a solution!  Ths all!
     
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            userList = new ArrayList<User>();
            sAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),userList);
            
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_employe, container, false);
    
            ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            lv.setAdapter(sAdapter);
    
            return rootView;
        }`

Answer (score 2):

`setListAdapter()` is a method in `ListFragment`..For this you need to extend `ListFragmnet` instead of `Fragment`.

Change this line

```
public class MyEmployeeFragment extends Fragment
```

into

```
public class MyEmployeeFragment extends ListFragment
```

Comment: I try to use `ListFragment` yet. But `FragmentTransaction` dont work. I want to use `Fragment`

Answer (score 1):

You need define the ListView first:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findById(android.R.id.list);
```

And later you need put the adapter:

```
list.setAdapter(sAdapter);
```

Or change

```
extends Fragment
```

to

```
extends ListFragment
```

Answer (score 0):

`extends ListFragment` should be working fine.

Below is a sample that works for me..

```
public class Chicks extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener  {

}
```