# setListAdapter() Gone Wrong

Tags: android

When I try to use setListAdapter to show my data this happens:

> Cannot resolve method setListAdapter

This is my Activity:

```
package id.sch.smktelkom.www.crud;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;

public class CollectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    FetchCollectListener {
    String[] daftar;
    ListView listView;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    Button search;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_collection);
        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cari);

        initView();


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent inte = new Intent(CollectionActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(inte);
            }
        });
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent c = new Intent(CollectionActivity.this, SearchV.class);
                startActivity(c);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initView() {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CollectionActivity.this, "", "Loading...");

        String url = "http://192.168.4.5/SqliteSync/readC.php";
        FetchCollection task = new FetchCollection(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }


    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Collect> data) {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        CollectAdapter adapter = new CollectAdapter(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
        // show failure message
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And this is my Adapter:

```
package id.sch.smktelkom.www.crud;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class CollectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Collect> {
    private List<Collect> items;
    private Context mContext;
    public CollectAdapter(Context context, List<Collect> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_collect, items);
        this.items = items;
        mContext = context;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.item_collect, null);
        }

        Collect app = items.get(position);

        if(app != null) {
            TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtpeminjam);
            TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtpinjaman);
            ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent b = new Intent(mContext,LihatDataActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(b);
                }
            });

            if(id != null) id.setText(app.getNama());

            if(name != null) name.setText(app.getPinjaman());

        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with this and it's annoying me already.

I want to retrieve data from MySQL to my Android app and when I type setListAdapter suddenly it becomes red and shows some error.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076767/cannot-resolve-method-setlistadapter

Comment: @Bayu: You are calling it from wrong place. Get a reference to your ListView say list1 and then call setAdapter on it: list1.setAdapter(adapter).

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: it works thanks !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `setListAdapter(adapter);` call `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

`setListAdapter` works for activities extending `ListActivity`

I see also that you should add in onCreate this:

```
ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

if the name of the `ListView` is `listView` in xml

Comment: and then this thing shows up java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: Did you add `ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);` in `onCreate` ?

Answer (score 0):

So after some advice from @AmitVikramSingh

I'm referencing my listview

```
public class CollectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FetchCollectListener {
String[] daftar;
ListView listView;

protected Cursor cursor;


Button search;

private ProgressDialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_collection);
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cari);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
```

And I change this from

```
    @Override
public void onFetchComplete(List<Collect> data) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
    // create new adapter
    CollectAdapter adapter = new CollectAdapter(this, data);
    // set the adapter to list
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

To this

```
    @Override
public void onFetchComplete(List<Collect> data) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
    // create new adapter
    CollectAdapter adapter = new CollectAdapter(this, data);
    // set the adapter to list
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Big thanks to all who help me solving this problem